# How to list a direct reports in Powershell

Tags: powershell

How to get displayname from direct reports attribute ?

```
Get-ADUser $foo  -Properties *  | select @{Name="directreports";Expression={($_.directreports | %{(Get-ADUser $_).displayname}) -Join ";"}}
```

Output :

```
directreports
-------------
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

ISSUE resolved :

```
Get-ADUser $foo  -Properties *  | select @{Name="directreports";Expression={($_.directreports | %{(Get-ADUser $_).name}) -Join ";"}}
```

Comment: No `manager` attribute ,I need is a list of a specific user's `direct reports` exported to a CSV.

Comment: Apologies, I deleted my comment as I realized my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for misreading your question, try out the below and let me know if this does what you want it to do?

```
Get-ADUser $foo -Properties * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectReports | ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Identity $_ | Select-Object Name }
```

You can always add on `| Export-CSV -Path "c:\temp\directreports.csv" -NoTypeInformation` at the end to get this out of course.

On your original code, the easiest way I found to expand out the list of direct reports was to do the select on it's own and then pipe into a foreach, rather than trying to do it all in one as an expression.

Also, `DisplayName` is not a default property returned by `Get-ADUser`, so this is why I used the `Name` property instead in my suggested solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks but I need it as an expression.

Comment: Any chance you can detail why this must be an expression?

Comment: I need to integrate other attributes such as givenname ,sn , employeeid.

Comment: you can always add other properties to the `Select-Object` command - glad you resolved your issue though, if you can please post it as an answer so other people can see and learn from it :)